# inserting node (Binary search tree) C

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to insert a node in a binary search tree and I'm getting a little problem.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct Node{
    char name[100];
    struct Node *pGauche;
    struct Node *pDroit;
}Node;

void getName(char[]);
void copy(Node **, Node *,char[]);
void menu(Node **);
void add(Node **);
void search(char[],Node**, Node **,Node **);
void print(Node **);
void inOrder(Node *);

void main(void)
{
    Node *root = NULL;
    menu(&root);
    system("pause");
}

void menu(Node **root)
{
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        add(root);
    }
    print(root);
}

void add(Node **root)
{
    char name[100];
    getName(name);
    Node *p = NULL;
    Node *savep = NULL;
    search(name,root,&p,&savep);
    copy(root,savep,name);
}

void search(char name[],Node **root, Node **p, Node **savep)
{
    *p = *root;

    while ((p == NULL) && (strcmp((*p)->name,name) != 0))
    {
        *savep = *p;

        if (strcmp(name,(*p)->name) < 0)
            *p = (*p)->pGauche;
        else
            *p = (*p)->pDroit;
    }

}

void getName(char name[])
{
    printf("What name do you want to add\n");
    scanf("%s",name);
    fflush(stdin);

}

void copy(Node **root, Node *savep, char name[])
{
    Node *newp = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node*));
    newp->pDroit = NULL;
    newp->pGauche = NULL;

    strcpy(newp->name,name);
    printf("%s",newp->name);


    if (*root == NULL)
        *root = newp;
    else
    {
        if (strcmp(name,savep->name) < 0) 
            savep->pGauche = newp;
        else
            savep->pDroit = newp;
    }
    free(newp);
}

void print(Node ** root)
{
    Node *p = *root;
    inOrder(p);
}

void inOrder(Node *p)
{
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        inOrder(p->pGauche);
        printf("%s\n",p->name);
        inOrder(p->pDroit);
    }
}
```

I know there are some really odd function and useless functions, but this just a "test" for a slightly bigger school project so it will get useful in time, right now I would just like to get the binary tree working !

So basically the problem is that I'm getting a "Access violation reading location" after I type in the second name... I'm guessing when doing the strcmp, but I'm really not sure :/

I'd really be glad if someone could help me getting this running :)

Comment: You should try running your code in a debugger to understand better why the code is crashing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things to get you started. I haven't looked into it too deeply, so you will probably have to continue to drill down into more issues, but fix these things just to get you started:

In this code in `search()`:

```
    while ((p == NULL) && (strcmp((*p)->name,name) != 0))
```

The `p` parameter will never be NULL. So, the while loop is never entered. This means that `savep` would not get set to any value, and is NULL when you call `copy()` in your `add()` function. The `copy()` function then dereferences the invalid pointer reference, which caused the problem you observed.

You actually want to test to see if `*p` is *NOT* NULL. This allows you to legally dereference it.

```
    while ((*p != NULL) && (strcmp((*p)->name,name) != 0))
```

Secondly, as `hmjd` identified, you do not allocate enough memory for your node inside `copy()`.

```
    Node *newp = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node*));
```

You are only allocating enough memory for one pointer, not for an entire node. Also, you should not cast the return value of `malloc()` when coding in C (it will hide a bug that can lead to a crash in the worst case).

```
    Node *newp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

Thirdly, you need to retain the memory you allocate for your nodes rather than freeing them immediately after inserting it at the end of `copy()`:

```
    // I need this memory for my tree!
    //free(newp);
```

If you call `free()` like you did, then your `tree` will be pointing into freed memory, and to access them would cause undefined behavior.

One minor thing: You shouldn't do `fflush(stdin)`, as `fflush()` is only for output streams.

Comment: And one for you. There are many bugs in the code as you have identified. There may be others but the OP can at least fix those listed and hopefully learn something. Enabling him/her to fix other bugs unmentioned in the answers.

Comment: Thanks a lot to you two guys, that was indeed very helpful and helped me learn from the mistakes I made :D
Everything is running smooth now !

Answer (score 3):

This is incorrect:

```
while ((p == NULL) && (strcmp((*p)->name,name) != 0))
```

and will result in a `NULL` pointer being dereferenced, which is undefined behaviour. Change to:

```
while (*p && strcmp((*p)->name,name) != 0)
```

---

This is incorrect:

```
Node *newp = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node*));
```

as it is only allocating enough for a `Node*`, when it needs to be allocating a `Node`. Change to:

```
Node *newp = malloc(sizeof(*newp));
```

and don't `free()` it in the same function as it is required later. `free()`ing the `Node` means the list has [dangling pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) and dereferencing one is undefined behaviour, and a probable cause of the access violation.

---

Note:

```
fflush(stdin);
```

is undefined behaviour. From the [`fflush()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) reference page:

> Causes the output file stream to be synchronized with the actual contents of the file. **If the given stream is of the input type, then the behavior of the function is undefined.**

Comment: Your analysis of what caused the asker's problem is incomplete.

Comment: @user315052, ok but it will help at least.

Comment: Yes, that's why I have +1'd you.